# Using OverBarred variables

Tags: replacement, custom-notation

Mathematica does not seem to treat variables as a unit. Consider the following:

```
rule = a -> Function[{x}, OverBar[a][x]]
test = a[x] /. rule;
test /. rule
```

It seems to apply the rule again on the last line, which of course is not what I want (in the sense that a and OverBar[a] are supposed to be different things). I tried to use the Notation package but was rather unsuccessful.
Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to replace `a` with `Overbar[a]`, but only if it isn't already inside `Overbar`.  So make `Overbar[a]->Overbar[a]` your first replacement rule, and it will be protected from further replacements:

```
rules = {OverBar[a] -> OverBar[a], a -> OverBar[a]};
test = a[x] /. rules
(* OverBar[a] *)

test /. rules
(* Overbar[a] *)
```

Comment: Very nice thank you. It seems that putting the Overbar[a]->Overbar[a] replacement last actually also work. I cannot understand what happens internally, however?